# C# Handle Batch Wise Database Querying with Parallel For

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library, parallel-foreach

I have a non parallel data querying stored procedure call. This is the query.

```
SELECT TOP(1000) a.[tableA_id] AS [id],a.[tableA_name],a.[tableA_modified]
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.[tableA_modified] = 1
    AND a.tableA_id NOT IN (
        SELECT tableA_id_foreign
        FROM tableB_id b
    )
```

This is that the c# code looks like.

```
for
{
  UpdateBatch(SpCall());
}
```

This SP call happens **batch wise**. After a processing of a batch done successfully, the column 'tableA_modified' is set to 0 of that batch. So in the next call, new batch is returned.

But now I want to do this SP call inside a **prallel for**. 
Now I want to implement it like this.

```
parallelfor
{
 UpdateBatch(SpCall());
}
```

But I can't use the 'TOP' because SP call happens parallely (So the tableA_modified is not set to 0 of the first 1000 rows). And I can't take the whole result too (Without limiting the first set to 1000), because that would create a timeout. Is there away to solve this.

Comment: You can try to use an page/offset in SQL, but make sure there is something safe you can order by. https://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by-offset-fetch and pass a page number to the stored procedure.  You'll still need to figure out which page each call is for.

Comment: you would need to count the total rows, then in c# create ranges which relate to batchs, and then pass the ranges into the parallel.foreach. Then have an SP, which would return a range of entries, `order by` the `id column` and `where` on the range `start > y` and `x < end`. this would mean that the select query would still stay perforant and the same rows would never be selected. ideally you would want to add a column to the table and call it batch, and pre-assign a batch_id, and process according to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a column to tableA (e.g. UpdateBatchId) then the procedure could be updated to receive an @UpdateBatchId parameter that would be set on the top 1000 rows (using the same where condition with an additional condition to include rows with a null UpdateBatchId).  Then it would return the records that were set with that specific UpdateBatchId:

```
UPDATE TOP(1000) SET a.UpdateBatchId = @UpdateBatchId
OUTPUT inserted.[tableA_id] AS [id], inserted.[tableA_name], inserted.[tableA_modified]
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.[tableA_modified] = 1
AND a.tableA_id NOT IN (
    SELECT tableA_id_foreign
    FROM tableB_id b
)
AND a.UniqueBatchId is null
```

Then in the SpCall you'd pass in a new unique update batch id. That could be derived from the code (e.g. a guid or something):

```
parallelfor
{
 UpdateBatch(SpCall(GetNewUniqueUpdateBatchId()));
}
```

The UpdateBatchId can also come from an identity column of another table (e.g. a table containing UpdateBatch data). If you use a table and an identity column then the query could also handle that part (inserting a row into the UpdateBatch table and using the identity column from that as the UpdateBatchId parameter to the Update), then the SpCall wouldn't need to come up with and pass the UpdateBatchId.

If you can't add a column to the table then you can do something similar with a new table that has two columns tableA_id and UpdateBatchId.

Comment: I wanted to implementing this without changing the database structure (Without adding new table or new column)

Comment: Is tableA_id a sequential identity column with minimal or no gaps?